# Execute shell script from power shell in windows machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute shell script from power shell in windows machine. So starting wrote the shell script and invoked into the linux box by using below command:

```
PS>.\pscp.exe .\abc.sh root@1.2.3.4:/root` and gave the permissions through power shell by using below command  
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "chmod +x abc.sh"` after that verified that shell script copied or not  
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "ls"
```

So it copied. After that when i am executing by using below command:

```
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "bash ./abc.sh"`
```

It's not working in the sense getting error like:

```
./abc.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found ./abc.sh: 
line 5: syntaxerror near unexpected token `$'\r'' '/abc.sh: 
line 5: `function abc()
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "./abc.sh"
bash: ./abc.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

If any valuable suggestions appreciable and thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install the package

```
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "yum install dos2unix -y"
```

after that run the below command

```
    PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "dos2unix abc.sh"
dos2unix: converting file abc.sh to UNIX format ...
```

after that assaign the execute permission to the script file

```
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "chmod + abc.sh"
```

at last give the script file path then your script will be executed.

```
PS>.\plink.exe -pw "L***e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "/root/abc.sh"
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used much windows text-editors, but "^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" - indicates that there is windows-version of carriage return. So it might help just to convert your script file to unix-style.

Reference: https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux